# Blender video editor cut strips issue

Tags: video-sequence-editor

I used to use Blender one year ago and just reinstalled it 2 days ago. I am facing an issue that seems to be a bug to me.

I am on archlinux, last 17:2.81.a-5 blender version with no library issue.

In video editor mode, I upload a mp4 video. When I cut (K) a strip in two strips, half the time (more or less) it cut it at the right time line but the cut is performed between 2 and 10 frames later in the time. I can not fins any sens to this behavior, so I think this is just a bug.

For example, I have a strip from 0 to 200 frames, I cut it at the frame 100 and now, the end of the left strip is corresponding to the 96th frame, not the 100th. So, I have 4 frames in the right strip that should be on the left strip.
It does it pretty randomly.
I tried all the different cuts (soft, hard), with keymap, without.
Could it be a bug from the last release?
Any idea?
Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0):

Your source file may have variable frame rate. You can use MediaInfo to check: https://mediaarea.net/en/MediaInfo
If it has VFR you'll need to re-encode it with ex. Handbreake or any other GUI for ffmpeg: https://handbrake.fr/

Comment: This is the right answer, I figured it out few days ago and was trying this solution.

Comment: @yoarch Please don't reply "Thanks" as an answer or comment, instead [upvote the post that helped you](https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/why-vote). If you feel it completely solved your issue consider [marking it as accepted](https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer).